# Solving PDE with Legendre functions

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials

I'm studying a paper which has a PDE of the form

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial L}(L,n) = A\bigg((n^2-1)\frac{\partial p}{\partial n}(L,n)\bigg),\quad n>1,$$
with a Dirac delta initial condition $p(L=0,n) = \delta(n-1).$ Also note that
$$n = \frac{2-\tau}{\tau},\quad \tau\in[0,1],\quad n\in[1,\infty).$$
To solve this PDE they then denote $P_{-\frac12+i\mu}(n),$ $n\geq1,\mu\geq 0$ the Legendre function of the first kind, which is the solution of

$$\frac{d}{dn}(n^2-1)\frac{d}{dn}P_{-\frac12+i\mu}(n) = \bigg(\mu^2+\frac14\bigg)P_{-\frac12+i\mu}(n),\quad P_{-\frac12+i\mu}(1)=1.$$ They then say that the Legendre function has the integral representation
$$P_{-\frac12+i\mu}(n) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\cosh{(\pi\mu)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{(\mu\tau)}}{\sqrt{\cosh{(\tau)}+n}}d\tau.$$

I'm completely stuck to how they get this integral representation, and why they would choose a Legendre polynomial of this form. I would really appreciate help on how to obtain this integral representation, thank you!

Comment: The Legendre functions are basically particular cases of the Gauss hypegeomteric function (see http://dlmf.nist.gov/14.3.E6). Your integral is formula (11) at the bottom of page 156 in https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43491/1/Volume%201.pdf There is an explanation in that book on how to arrive at this representation.

Comment: Thank you greatly for this reference!

Comment: @Gary I understand how the integral representation is formulated, but why is the certain $-\frac12+i\mu$ chosen for the Legendre function?

Comment: It should be clear from the derivation in the paper.